# Deploying a React App to AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a website using express/ react which consist of two separate parts. 
1- API app (express server)
2- Website (react app)

I was fiddling around with AWS to deploy my app and figured out few options. So far the best option for the API is to use Elastic Beanstalk. It works well and I had no issues with it.

The confusing part is the react app. I have deployed it once as Elastic Beanstalk and once as S3 bucket. Both worked with some challenges ( easier was the S3)

I want to ask if anyone has been in the same scenario and have any recommendations?

Comment: React is just a development framework-
At the end of the day you are serving an html,js,css files, you can use express to do so.

Comment: hi Idan thanks for the response. i get that but my question is more of best practice / recommendations

Comment: You can go pretty far by serving it in your already set server.
If you'll need scaling you can just scale your server.
Your app is just a simple file, which probably weights much less than your images.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is better (for the sake of better scalability) to split the API server and CDN for bundled React App. You can use the [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) as CDN for the App and [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) as API.

Comment: Thanks Dennis , how did you deal with the proxy for the API calls ?

in create-react-app it is very simple to add the proxy to the package.json .. however on production the only way i got the api to work is by allowing CORS

Comment: @MoatazWesimy [There](https://serverfault.com/questions/833360/what-aws-service-to-avoid-cors-issues-with-s3-static-content-and-aws-backends) is a good answer to this question. In essence, you can tweak CFs origins and behaviours settings a lot.

Comment: @MoatazWesimy great! You can accept the answer if it was helpful. The checkmark on the side of the answer, near the 0.